# not getting synchronous data from redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, reducers, redux-actions

**action** creator

```
export function pickup(latlng) {

    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: PICKUP_STATE,payload:latlng });
    };

}
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
    PICKUP_STATE,
    PICKUP_ADD,
    DROPOFF_STATE
} from '../actions/types';

export default  (state={},action) => {
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        pickup: '',
        pickupAdd:''
    };
    switch(action.type) {
        case PICKUP_STATE:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {...state,pickup:action.payload};
        case PICKUP_ADD:
            return{...state,pickupAdd:action.payload};
        case DROPOFF_STATE:
            return {...state,dropoff:action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
    //return state;
}
```

**Map** component

```
import {
    connect
} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions"
class Map extends React.Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
             if (nextprops.pickupProps !== undefined) {
                 this.setState({
                     pick: nextprops.pickupProps
                 }, () => {
                     console.log(this.state.pick);

                 });
             }
       }
   isPickEmpty(emptyPickState) {
        this.props.pickup(emptyPickState);
    // setTimeout(() =>{ console.log('sdkjlfjlksd',this.state.pick) 
                        },3000);
        console.log(this.state.pick);
   }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // console.log(state.BookingData.pickup);
    return {
        pickupProps:state.BookingData.pickup,
        pickupAddProps: state.BookingData.pickupAdd
        }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(Map);
```

**app.js** root file

```
import React        from "react";
import ReactDOM     from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import "normalize.css/normalize.css"
import  "./styles/styles.scss";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {AUTH_USER} from "./actions/types";


const middleware = [
    reduxThunk,
];

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
// other store enhancers if any
));



const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

here my problem is when i'm calling **isPickEmpty()** from my map component
it invoke **action** creator **this.props.pickup(false)** (i also checked in `redux-devtools` it show **false** value) then i'm consoling **pick state**( which store in  `componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops)`) so it showing **default value** instead of `false` 
**but when i'm consoling the value inside  `setTimeout(() =>{console.log('sdkjlfjlksd',this.state.pick) }, 3000);` it showing `false` value**
correct me if i'm wrong **what i know that redux-thunks works in synchronous manner not asynchronous manner** so here why it's not working in synchronous manner
i'm stuck,plz anyone help me!
**Update**
i just got where the prblm, actually in **componentWillReceiveProps** where i'm setting pick state value because it is asynchronous so when i'm fetching the value in **isPickEmpty** function i'm getting prev value.
**how handle setState or is there any way to solve**

Answer (score 0):

At the component you use the values in  `BookingData`, but on the reducer you add it direct to the state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);//Check the state here
    return {
        pickupProps:state.pickup,
        pickupAddProps: state.pickupAdd
        }
}
```

Should work well if you se this `mapStateToProps`

Comment: no,acutally i created one **index** reducer file there i added this file as a **BookingData**. prblm is not that because i'm getting the data asynchronously but i want synchronous data in redux thunk.you can see that in **isPickEmpty** after **setIntervel** i'm getting the data.